# Validating multiple asyncronous methods in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am looking at a code that I have to work on.  And basically I have to add a validation to a listener of a button.
The code has already multiple validations.  They are kind of set in a cascade. 
The listener of the buttons calls an asyncCallBack method that if everything is ok, on the onsuccess part of the method calls for the next one, an that one on the next one, until it reaches the end and goes to the next page.  I am not a fan of this approach because it is kind of messy.  What would the best way to do that using best practices.

An example of the code:

```
Button btnOK = new Button("Aceptar");
btnOK.addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<ButtonEvent>() {
public void handleEvent(ButtonEvent e) {
    myService.getInfo1(1, txt, "N",
        new AsyncCallback<List<InfoService>>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // goes back
                return
            }

            public void  onSuccess(
                List<Object> result) {
                    // do some validation with the result
                    validation2();
                }

        }
    }
}

public void validation2(){
    myService.getDireccionCanalesElectronicos(id, new AsyncCallback<MyResult>() {
        public void onSuccess(MyResult result) {
            // do some validation with the result
            validation3();
        }
        ...
    }
}

public void validation3(){
    myService.getDireccionCanalesElectronicos(id, new AsyncCallback<MyResult>() {
        public void onSuccess(MyResult result) {
            // do some validation with the result
            validation4();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this, it seems messy and hard to follow. Adding another validation is complicated. It doesnt seem like a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 1 method in the servlet that calls all the validation methods and do just one call in the client ?

```
public void validation()
{
   boolean ok = validation1();
  if (ok) ok = validation2();

  return validation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using mirco services is sometimes hard to deal with. As @Knarf mentioned, this is a way to go. But sometime you may want to handle the calls on the client side. Another one will be using this tiny framework: [sema4g](https://github.com/mvp4g/sema4g). It will help you to solve your problem.

A solution might look like that:

First create the sem4g commands:

```
private SeMa4gCommand createGetInfoCommand() {
  return new AsyncCommand() {
    // create callback
    MethodCallbackProxy<List<InfoService>> proxy = new MethodCallbackProxy<List<InfoService>>(this) {
      @Override
      protected void onProxyFailure(Method method,
                                    Throwable caught) {
        // Enter here the code, that will
        // be executed in case of failure
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProxySuccess(Method method,
                                    List<InfoService> response) {
        // Enter here the code, that will
        // be executed in case of success
      }
    };

    @Override
    public void execute() {
      // That's the place for the server call ...
      myService.getInfo1(1, txt, "N", proxy);
    }
  };
}
```

do that for all your calls;

```
private SeMa4gCommand createCommandGetDireccionCanalesElectronicos() {
  return new AsyncCommand() {
    // create callback
    MethodCallbackProxy<MyResult> proxy = new MethodCallbackProxy<MyResult>(this) {
      @Override
      protected void onProxyFailure(Method method,
                                    Throwable caught) {
        // Enter here the code, that will
        // be executed in case of failure
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProxySuccess(Method method,
                                    List<MyResult>  response) {
        // Enter here the code, that will
        // be executed in case of success
      }
    };

    @Override
    public void execute() {
      // That's the place for the server call ...
      myService. getDireccionCanalesElectronicos(id, proxy);
    }
  };
}
```

Once you have done this for all your calls, create a sema4g context and run it:

```
  try {
    SeMa4g.builder()
      .addInitCommand(new InitCommand() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStart() {
                              // Enter here your code, that
                              // should be executed when
                              // the context is started
                            })
      .addFinalCommand(new FinalCommand() {
                             @Override
                             public void onSuccess() {
                               // Enter here the code, that will
                               // be executed in case the context
                               // ended without error
                             }

                             @Override
                              public void onFailure() {
                                // Enter here the code, that will
                                // be executed in case the context
                                // ended with an error
                              })
      .add(createGetInfoCommand())
      .add(createCommandGetDireccionCanalesElectronicos())
      .build()
      .run();
  } catch (SeMa4gException e) {
    // Ups, something wrong with the context ...
  }
```

For more informations, read the documentation. If you have questions, feel free to ask: [SeMa4g Gitter room](https://gitter.im/SeMa4g/Lobby).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that the client is very picky about adding more dependencies. I would certainly look into this in my next project

Comment: no problem, both solutions work. In my case, we have to do a lot of calls from the client side and want to do them parallel.